# TForm created dynamically won't set focus to edit control when calling ShowModal()

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I created a `TForm` in the IDE of C++Builder with `BorderStyle=bsDialog` and made it available following this tutorial:

[Dynamically Creating a VCL Modal Form](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Dynamically_Creating_a_VCL_Modal_Form).

I then POST a custom message in the `MainForm::OnShow()` event, which then sets a FireDAC connection to `true` which has the `LoginPrompt` property enabled and uses the `OnLogin()` event, which then opens up my form.

My issue is that my `TEdit` field does not get the focus when the dialog is opened.  The form contains a `TImage` using an icon, a `TGradientLabel`, a `TEdit`, a `TStaticText`, and two `TButtons` for **Ok** (default) and **Cancel**.   When the form is first opened, pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> makes the focus go to the **Ok** button, but without the dashed line to indicate input focus; using <kbd>Shift-Tab</kbd> goes to the **Cancel** button, but without the dashed line to indicate input focus. After pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Shift-Tab</kbd>, the next <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Shift-Tab</kbd> works and has the dashed line (when on a button).  When the form is first opened, if you <kbd>Tab</kbd> then <kbd>Shift-Tab</kbd>, or <kbd>Shift-Tab</kbd> then <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the `TEdit` field has the cursor and input like it should have from the start.

Here's basically how I setup / start the form:

```cpp
MyForm=new TMyForm(MainForm);
MyForm->ActiveControl=MyForm->EditName;
MyForm->ShowModal();
MyForm->Free();
```

I found that if I click another Window then click back to my Main Window (or even if I just click on itself on the Taskbar), it also works and the `TEdit` control has the cursor.

I even tried setting up an event for `OnShow` for the dialog, and used `::SetForegroundWindow()`, `::SetActiveWindow()` for the Form, and tried again setting `ActiveControl`, and even using `MyForm->SetFocus()`, but nothing is working.

I'm using Windows 10, is there something else that needs to be done (clearly there is)?

Comment: At what point do you issue the PostMessage call? It might be too early (so that the VCL overrides whatever you do in your PostMessage message handler).

Comment: Sorry but I'm trying to understand why you keep adding the Delphi tag if this is only C++ related?

Comment: @Adriaan Presumably asker will accept answers with Delphi syntax as well as C++ syntax. C++ Builder users might have a good knowledge of Delphi too, you know.

Comment: @Adriaan because it's basically all the same and there is a larger delphi group that knows VCL which is what the questions are about, not the programming language.

Comment: @user3161924 one problem with using the [tag:delphi] and [tag:c++builder] tags together is that code snippets end up using the Delphi language highlighter by default, not the C++ syntax highlighter.  You have to explicitly specify the highlighter in each code snippet to fix that.

Comment: @user3161924 FYI, you can set the `ActiveControl` in the Object Inspector at design-time, you don't have to set it in code at runtime. Also, you should be using the `delete` operator instead of calling `Free()` directly (the [documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TObject.Free) even says so): "***Note**: In C++ code, do not use `Free` to destroy an object. Use the `delete` keyword.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau  I do have it set there too, I just set in code to ensure it's set and for showing it is set so others don't think that was the issue.  On the other item I was just following the docs from https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Dynamically_Creating_a_VCL_Modal_Form but can change to delete.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm not sure of the details of what is going on internally (not sure how to get spy++ to watch the messages of a Window before the Window exist), but I solved the issue by simply retrying the custom message (`UWM_MAINDIALOGSHOWN`) again multiple times, I got it down that even 1 time is enough.  I put this at the top of my custom message:

```cpp
static int redo=1;
if (redo) {
    redo--;
    PostMessage(Handle, UWM_MAINDIALOGSHOWN, 0, 0);
    return;
}
```

If someone has more details on the internals, that be great, but at least there is something that works if someone else runs in to this.

Comment: I believe you can set Spy++ to monitor windows that belong to specific proces/application. This should then also capture messages from a newly created windows.

Comment: I did a break OnShow, got the handle manually, typed in to spy++, and the the only message between the two WM_APP messages is `message: 0xC111 [Registered: "TaskbarButtonCreated"] wParam:00000000 lParam:00000000`

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for manually setting focus to your `TEdit` control if you have designed your form dialog properly.

You see at Design time you control the order of visiting between focusable components by setting their [TabOrder](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.TabOrder) propery.

By default form designer sets `TabOrder` property based on the order of components you already placed on your form. So for instance if you have placed the two buttons first and then the edit control it will have its `TabOrder` set to 2.

So all you have to do to solve your problem is to simply change the `TabOrder` property of your `TEdit` component to 0 which will make sure it is focused when the form is shown.

If you have multiple `TEdit` controls (username and password) set username edit `TabOrder` property to 0 and password edit `TabOrder` property to 1. This way user can move from username to password control using Tab key.

Comment: The TabOrder was correct, Even tried changing order of creation.  The issue was deeper, see the answer.

Comment: That makes no sense. Granted I'm working with Delphi instead of C++ builder but both use same VCL library so there should be no different behavior between them. Can you post a DFM of your dialog form?

Comment: Even if I try to dynamically create a dialog form entirely from code I can not reproduce your problem. Setting the `TabOrder` property always solves the problem. But I do set this before showing the dialog form.

Comment: see the details in the question - it's OnShow post, there is clearly something that happens (a message) after the POST internally that changes the focus.  Waiting one more POST to the queue fixes it.  See answer people are voting down, but it's the answer and fixes it.

Comment: I can't recreate your problem in Delphi but I don't have access to C++ builder. Even your basic code of setting up your modal form work just fine in Delphi. So either there is a significant difference between Delphi and C++ VCL which I doubt or or there is some additional code of your that might be affecting this that you are not showing us. So at this point I have to ask you to provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can veriffy the cause is either in your code or VCL difference.